# Regex find only 1 occurrence issue

Tags: .net, regex

I need to find line :

```
echo "PB702101 not executed"
```

in:

```
if test ${csis_batch_completion} -le ${csis_batch_warning} ;then
  echo "Running PB702101"
  run ${csis_obj}/PB702101
  display_completion
else
  echo "PB702101 not executed"
fi
```

I am currently using:

```
^(?!#)..echo ""((?!""))(\b.*?) not executed""$
```

but I keep getting :

```
  echo "Running PB702101"
  run ${csis_obj}/PB702101
  display_completion
else
  echo "PB702101 not executed"
```

How do I get only the last occurrence of echo with "XXXX not executed"?

Comment: Is it .net code ?

Comment: if you want to put that fact inside the pattern you may use `.+(echo\s+".+?not executed")` and the capturing group will hold the last echo line because the quantifier in `.+` will behave greedy. Otherwise you could simplify the regex focusing on the echo alone and just return the last occurence found by your regex engine (that you didn't cite but maybe it's .net since the tag used)

Comment: Yes it's .net,  also I only want the group to contain PB702101 and nothing else.

Comment: Also the match must be only :echo "PB702101 not executed"
if I your your example it will match on everything before not executed

Comment: Example at :https://regex101.com/r/aZj78t/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. It excludes all preliminary text, thereby getting the last one only.

```
@"(?s)echo[ ]""\w+[ ]not[ ]executed""(?!.*echo[ ]""\w+[ ]not[ ]executed"")"
```

https://regex101.com/r/TTTmwS/1

Answer (score 0):

With the following regex you'll match the whole string with the capturing group holding the code (PB702101 in your example) that follows the latest echo line:

```
.+echo\s+"(.+?)not executed"
```

And this is the snippet to run it with c#:

```
string input = 
 "if test ${csis_batch_completion} -le ${csis_batch_warning} ;then\n" +
 "  echo \"Running PB702101\"\n" +
 "  run ${csis_obj}/PB702101\n" +
 "  display_completion\n" +
 "else\n" +
 "  echo \"PB702101 not executed\"\n" +
 "fi";
        
string pattern = @".+echo\s+""(.+?)not executed""";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success)
  Console.WriteLine("Capturing Group: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
else
  Console.WriteLine("No match found.");
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SF5luh